# why validation does not work in my code?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation, inputfield

I have only 1 input in my form which is why the reduce method doesn't work but how to validate the form without this method.Already a lot of things tried but the result is not achieved......
My JS controller

```
var valid = component.find('CommentForm').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
            // Displays error messages for invalid fields
            inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
        }, true);
```

my component

```
<aura:component description="CommentForm">
    <aura:attribute name="NewComment" type="Comment__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Comment__c','Name':'',
                        'Comment__c': '','Dish__c':''}"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="addComment" type="c:AddCommentEvent"/>
    <form class="slds-form--stacked">
        <lightning:textarea aura:id="CommentForm"  label="Comment"
                            name="CommentForm"
                            value="{!v.NewComment.Comment__c}"
                            required="true" maxlength="2000" messageWhenValueMissing="Complete this field" messageWhenTooLong="maxlength 2000 characters"/>
        <lightning:button label="Create Comment"
                          class="slds-m-top--medium"
                          variant="brand"
                          onclick="{!c.clickCreateComment}"/>
    </form>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Hello sirs .Please tell me why validation does not work in my code.I read a lot of things but I would like to do it this way.I will be grateful

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to be more specific than "does not work". What behavior do you expect? What behavior do you observe? What are you trying to achieve at a high level?

Comment: Action failed: c:CommentForm$controller$clickCreateComment [component.find(...).reduce is not a function]

Comment: Not in the comments. Once again, please **[edit]** your post with these clarifications. What are you expecting the validation to do?

Comment: I have only 1 input in my form which is why the reduce method doesn't work but how to validate the form without this method

Comment: Once again, please **[edit]** your post to include any clarifications to your question. That's not what comments are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very painfully, `component.find` has 3 possible return values:

- undefined
- single component
- component array

Always returning an array of 0, 1 or more entries would be more helpful and the addition of a `findAll` method for that to the framework would be great.

In your case you only have one matching component so you are getting a single component returned not an array and the `reduce` method is only available on arrays.

Something like this will handle both cases (if you expect to add more fields):

```
[].concat(component.find('CommentForm')).reduce(...);
```

because `[]` is an array and `concat` concatenates either a single value or an array to the array. Note though that null is not mapped to an empty array though.

Comment: This is why my helpers usually have a method like this: `findList: function(component, name) { var results = component.find(name) || []; return results.length >= 0? results: [results]; }`

Comment: ...And I like your method better. I'm going to steal it now.

Comment: @sfdcfox We all learnt a long time ago not to pass nulls instead of empty arrays in other situation/languages. Think this multiple return types is a very bad design decision in the framework that I expect trips up just about everybody at some point.

Comment: Yeah, I would have expected component.find to behave more like jQuery's `$()` selector method; it always returns an array, even if the array may be empty. And most of Apex Code works that way, too. It's just odd that they felt it should return one of three different outcomes.

Comment: @sfdcfox Given it's too late now to change the behaviour of `find`, I'd +1 the addition of a `findAll` that always returned an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one element, you only need to check that one element:

```
var commentForm = component.find('CommentForm'), valid;
commentForm.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
valid = commentForm.get("v.validity").valid;
```